# Receiving ACPI error message while installing Zorin OS. What is going on here?

Tags: linux

While installing Zorin OS, every 5-10 seconds I get the error message below, which only goes away by clicking the power button once. What is going on here?

It also pauses the installation everytime. When the system is installed, everything is fine.

```
[ 1451.489768] ACPI Error: AE_ERROR, Returned by Handler for [UserDefinedRegion] (20210331/evregion-281)
[ 1451.489768] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.STR0._TMP due to previous error (AE_Error) (20210331/psparse-529)
[ 1550.434989] ACPI Error: AE_ERROR, Returned by Handler for [UserDefinedRegion] (20210331/evregion-281)
[ 1550.434989] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ00._TMP due to previous error (AE_Error) (20210331/psparse-529)
```

[image: Image. A screenshot of the error messages listed above]